# How to make one radio button option should be checked by default in angular repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

How to make one radio button option should be checked by default.
I tried to give `ng-model`, and `ng-init` but its not working.

My Html :

```
<div bindonce ng-repeat="row in results.favorites" style="padding: 0px 10px; white-space: nowrap; border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef; border-top: 1px solid #eee;  border-left: 1px solid #efefef;">
    <input type="radio" ng-click="setFavoriteDashboard(row.id)" ng-model="selectedRow" name="favRadioSel" style="opacity: 1;" class="pointer"/>
    <span bo-text="row.title" style="margin: 10px; position: relative; top: 3px;"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

I have given `checked="checked"` also but it is default selecting last value I want first option should be checked by default.

My JS:

```
$scope.results = {
  favorites: [{
    id: "WatchList1",
    title: "WatchList1"
  }, {
    id: "WatchList2",
    title: "WatchList2"
  }, {
    id: "WatchList3",
    title: "WatchList3"
  }]
};
$scope.selectedRow = "WatchList1";
```

Added Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/KA9HyQ3bHxJo2Cm9qFm3?p=preview

Comment: I edited my code.. PLease see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `radio` element should have its unique value and just bind it with `ng-model`. In your controller, set on your model the value of your first radio element.

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="setFavoriteDashboard(row.id)" ng-model="selectedRow" value="{{ row.id }}" name="favRadioSel" style="opacity: 1;" class="pointer"/>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.selectedRow = "" //value of your first row.id
```

Working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/cNcgeGZPvQKTgOtgaUqE?p=preview

Comment: Its not working.. I edited my code.. Can you help please ?

Comment: I've updated the anwser, you were using `ng-value` but you need use `value` in order to have the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

each radio button need ng-model! please check oficial [page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) for easy to understand code which you can edit in plunker and play around.

Your `ng-model="selectedRow"` should be an object with id property. Please see working example in my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/S0gQp8J46Y2MbMEZJsNS?p=preview)

Comment: check please the plumker from the page, to select on of the color in the example they put $scope.color = { name: 'blue' }; if you change to red for example radio button with red will be selected. You need to set your selected option on the $scope. Hope it helps.

Comment: check my version of plunker please